Database structure for Products/variants/bundles/carts
I got a scenario where i need to design a SQL db structure over MariaDB but i am not a Database Architect and i want to do it right the first try.
So, i have a products table which, for the sake of readability, has 2 fields, id and name. I have no idea how to make this graphic so i'll use json to define it:
productColumns = {
    id: "INTEGER",
    name: "STRING",
}

Then i have the variants table:
variantsColumns = {
    id: "INTEGER",
    name: "STRING",
    product_id: "INTEGER",
}

Now the goal. I need to add a Bundles and Carts. Bundles have to contain multiple products with a specified variant. Carts have to contain multiple products with a specified variant and also bundles. Now i need the ability to also add discounts to carts and bundles as a whole but also to add discounts to specific products from the cart or from the bundle.
What i thought:
bundlesColumns: {
    id: "INTEGER",
    name: "STRING",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE"
    discount: "INTEGER"
}

bundleItems: {
    id: "INTEGER",
    bundle_id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE",
    discount: "INTEGER",
    product_id: "INTEGER",
    variant_id: "INTEGER",
    quantity: "INTEGER",
}

carts: {
    id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE"
    discount: "INTEGER"
}

cartItems: {
    id: "INTEGER",
    cart_id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE",
    discount: "INTEGER",
    product_id: "INTEGER",
    variant_id: "INTEGER",
    bundle_id: "INTEGER",
    quantity: "INTEGER"
}

I have designed a few databases before but something about this structure feels off, looks like it's gonna be a pain in the *** for future development and wanted to get your opinion on this. Is there a better way to do this?

Your issue (the "gut feeling" you have) is related to this denormalized design:
cartItems: {
    id: "INTEGER",
    cart_id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE",
    discount: "INTEGER",
    product_id: "INTEGER",
    variant_id: "INTEGER",
    bundle_id: "INTEGER",
    quantity: "INTEGER"
}

This is allowing cartItems to be two completely different types of things: a bundle and a single product. This is an example of a Polymorphic Association. Your existing design can only be rectified by the use of a CHECK constraint
CHECK (product_id IS NOT NULL AND variant_id IS NOT NULL OR bundle_id IS NOT NULL)

This can make this table somewhat unwieldy to use, as joining to it can become conditional.

Alternative designs include:

Every ProductVariant is listed individually on the Cart, but some are associated with Bundles as well.

Make product_id and variant_id compulsory (non-nullable) and have the three-pair (product_id, variant_id, bundle_id) be foreign-keyed to bundleItems.
FOREIGN KEY (product_id, variant_id, bundle_id) REFERENCES bundleItems (product_id, variant_id, bundle_id)

On that note, bundleItems is a join table, and therefore should not have a separate id column. Instead it's primary key should be a composite key made up of those same three columns.
This design also has the downside that you cannot enforce the whole Bundle is added, only part of one.


Separate out these two types of products into two separate tables:

cartProducts: {
    cart_id: "INTEGER",
    product_id: "INTEGER",
    variant_id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE",
    discount: "INTEGER",
    quantity: "INTEGER"
}

cartBundles: {
    cart_id: "INTEGER",
    bundle_id: "INTEGER",
    discount_type: "PERCENTAGE|ABSOLUTE",
    discount: "INTEGER",
    quantity: "INTEGER"
}

Note the lack of an id column, as the composite columns denote the primary key.
This design is the most normalized, but can be a little bit unwieldy to query, as you need to query both tables separately and union the results.


Make every product a Bundle of at least one item, then a Cart can only contain Bundles not Items.

This can be rather heavy in terms of storage if there are only a few items that actually need to be bundled, but is the easiest to query.

Thank you for your answer! i kind of like this approach, seems less prone to idiotic errors: Separate out these two types of products into two separate tables. But now, i have another thing to think of. The bundles table is going to be automatically populated based on user preferences by an ai model. So basically each customer will  have his/her own unique bundles so it might get to a pretty big number. Do you think this approach will keep a good enough response time?

Probably just a matter of correct indexing: a B+tree index has O(N*Log(N)) complexity so even a billion row table has a very fast lookup time. As long as you don't scan large parts of the table and are instead looking up by key you should be OK.

This just became 10x more difficult and i need an idea again. The bundle can have multiple products that each has more variants. The products are set but the variants can be chosen by the user and then added to the cart. So i can't save only the bundle_id i need to save the combination for each product and variant. For example the bundle can have Shampoo with variants 50ml/60ml i need to store somehow the combination that the client has chosen.any ideas?

I suggest you create a new question for that, and please add sample input data as well. Sounds like you'd want a cart_bundle table, then a cart_bundle_product_variant table which FKs to the cart_bundle as well as the bundle_product and the product_variant tables, or something similar

You can create following tables and indexes
-- Products Table
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Index on the name column for quicker search by product name
CREATE INDEX idx_product_name ON products(name);

-- Variants Table
CREATE TABLE variants (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Index on product_id to optimize joins between products and variants
CREATE INDEX idx_variant_product_id ON variants(product_id);

-- Product-Variant Relationships Table (Optional, if different variants have different prices or other unique attributes)
CREATE TABLE product_variants (
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    variant_id INT NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10, 2),  -- Optional field
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, variant_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES variants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Index on price for filtering based on variant price
CREATE INDEX idx_product_variant_price ON product_variants(price);

-- Bundles Table
CREATE TABLE bundles (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Bundle Items Table
CREATE TABLE bundle_items (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    bundle_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    variant_id INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (bundle_id) REFERENCES bundles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES variants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Indexes for bundle_items to speed up joins and searches on bundle_id, product_id, and variant_id
CREATE INDEX idx_bundle_items_bundle_id ON bundle_items(bundle_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_bundle_items_product_id ON bundle_items(product_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_bundle_items_variant_id ON bundle_items(variant_id);

-- Carts Table
CREATE TABLE carts (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,  -- Optional: If associated with a specific user
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- Index on user_id for quick retrieval of carts associated with a specific user
CREATE INDEX idx_cart_user_id ON carts(user_id);

-- Cart Items Table
CREATE TABLE cart_items (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cart_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT,
    variant_id INT,
    bundle_id INT,  -- If item is from a bundle
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES carts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (variant_id) REFERENCES variants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (bundle_id) REFERENCES bundles(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

-- Indexes for cart_items to speed up joins and searches on cart_id, product_id, variant_id, and bundle_id
CREATE INDEX idx_cart_items_cart_id ON cart_items(cart_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cart_items_product_id ON cart_items(product_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cart_items_variant_id ON cart_items(variant_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cart_items_bundle_id ON cart_items(bundle_id);

-- Discounts Table
CREATE TABLE discounts (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    discount_type ENUM('PERCENTAGE', 'ABSOLUTE') NOT NULL,
    discount_value DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    applicable_type ENUM('BUNDLE', 'CART', 'PRODUCT') NOT NULL,
    applicable_id INT NOT NULL,
    precedence INT DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (applicable_id) REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Indexes on applicable_type and applicable_id for faster filtering by type and associated entity
CREATE INDEX idx_discounts_applicable_type ON discounts(applicable_type);
CREATE INDEX idx_discounts_applicable_id ON discounts(applicable_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_discounts_precedence ON discounts(precedence);


What stops you inserting a single row into cart_items which has all of product_id variant_id bundle_id assigned, or none, or any combination therein?

Thanks for your answer. So pretty similar to what i did besides the discounts table. But you reminded me about the indexes, forgot about that. Also, as Charlie said i need to create a custom rule for the cart_items to at least one product_id or bundle_id to not be null and if one is null the other to be null.
